# Need help making a Bootable USB

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, live-usb

I am not sure if this question has been asked. But I am unable to boot my laptop as I receive an error stating that no OS is installed. I have no other PCs around, but I do have my phone, my tablet, and a two-sided USB stick (one with standard USB, and the other with a Micro USB input).

I want to make my USB stick into a bootable Ubuntu live USB, but do not have the applications necessary to make one as I need a PC to use the applications.

I have done some research and came across an Android app that can turn your device into a bootable USB, but this does not work for me. The computer does not recognize the device (even after changing boot order), but it recognizes my USB stick.

Is there anything I can do? Is it possible to use Ubuntu Touch from my tablet to create a bootable USB, or does anyone know of an Android app that can do this?

I do not have a CD drive.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance, favour returned, Q upvoted!  You're a Rep 8 user already!

Comment: Great question! You just need a couple different tags!

Comment: Any suggestions on tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VeryEasyWay™ to do this:

Drop by one of your friends (Real friends, not the FaceBook variety), bring a six-pack of beer, ask them if you can borrow their Ubuntu computer and Internet connection for 20 minutes, let them drink the beer, "burn" your USB, go home, boot your PC, [Install Ubuntu using these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

The difficult way to do this:

[Ask one of our brethren on Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) how to create a bootable USB using your Android phone.